# Contamination delay of 74 series chips

Tags: digital-logic, timing-analysis

I'm a beginner in digital design, so my question might seem dumb. But how can I get the contamination delays of common 74 series chips?

[This](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/SN74HC04) is the datasheet for 7404, but it only mentions the propagation delay.

EDIT: I'm currently reading Digital Design and Computer Architecture. According to the textbook, the **contamination delay** tcd is the minimum time from when any input changes until any output starts to change its value.

Comment: "Well-balanced circuits will have similar speeds for all paths through a combinational stage, so the minimum propagation time is close to the maximum. This corresponding maximum time is the propagation delay."

Comment: I haven't run into "contamination delay" in my 50 years as an EE.  Did you mean "combinatorial delay?"  That's an old term for the maximum total delay in a combinatorial circuit (sum of propagation delays in series).

Comment: What does "contamination delay" mean?

Comment: Your description is about propagation delay. I have never heard about contamination delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contamination delay is the time from when an input changes to when the output can possibly begin to change.

The term seems to be a modern invention, and most SSI/MSI logic data sheets were written before that. The data sheets call it the "minimum propagation delay", or \$t_{pd(min)}\$.

In contrast, the maximum propagation delay \$t_{pd(max)}\$ is the time after which the output is guaranteed to be stable and correct.

Unfortunately, the datasheet you linked to doesn't provide minimum values for \$t_{pd}\$ (they used to), so you'll have to assume that they're zero.

Answer (score 0):

'Contamination delay' is **not** a commonly used term outside of a textbook.

Maybe if you want to estimate it you can take the ratio between typical and maximum tpd and apply that to the typical, with adjustments for Vcc. The result is probably conservative-- like two or three ns in the case of your 74HC04 operating from a 4.5 to 5.5V Vcc.